# Integration testing login with oauth using Rails, Capybara and Selenium?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, selenium, oauth, capybara

I created a simple Rails 4 app that uses Facebook to login. I'm writing a feature test that would allow me to sign in to Github and verify that it redirects back to my home page.

The problem:

- Facebook app is configured to respond to `localhost:5000`.
- Selenium browser launches app in `127.0.0.1:5723`

So the login fails.

```
require 'rails_helper'

describe 'the registration process', js: true do
  it 'signs me in using Github' do
    visit root_path

```
click_link 'Sign up / Login'
find("a[href='/users/auth/facebook']").click
within('.auth-form-body') do
  fill_in 'login', with: 'foobar'
  fill_in 'password', with: 'barbaz'
end
click_button 'Sign in'
```

end
end
```

What can I do to configure Selenium to use the same old `localhost:5000`?

Comment: Just a doubt, cant you use visit 'http://localhost:5000' of capybara dsl to route to port 5000

Answer (score 0):

```
Capybara.server_port = 8200
```

This worked. And I found it from [When running selenium with capybara/rails, how do I configure the server?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8413443/when-running-selenium-with-capybara-rails-how-do-i-configure-the-server)