# Capybara: how to run code when server is spawned?

Tags: ruby, webpack, capybara, sinatra, acceptance-testing

I have a Sinatra application with WebPack, when I start my app in development I spawn a process running Webpack Dev Server and use RackProxy to serve assets from my Sinatra app.

I also have to run Webpack Dev Server when running my JS Capybara acceptance tests just when Capybara spawns the ruby server.

So far I've came up with placing the WDS start in the driver register block, but I have different drivers.

```
Capybara.register_driver :headless_chrome do |app|
  Rack::WebpackProxy.start_server

  Capybara::Selenium::Driver.new(app, browser: :chrome, args: ["headless"])
end
```

What is the hook to run code when Capybara server is spawned?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8413443/when-running-selenium-with-capybara-rails-how-do-i-configure-the-server should help I think

Comment: Hi Mark, not quite, I need to do some work when capybara spawns it's servers, is not about configuring the driver or the server.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Capybara.server=` takes the registered name of the server proc to use when starting the server, and you can register your own using `Capybara.register_server`.  Therefore you should be able to do something like

```
Capybara.register_server :my_server do |app, port, host, **options|
  # start whatever you need started here
  do_my_stuff
  Capybara.servers[:puma].call(app, port, host) # assuming you want puma as the actual server
end

Capybara.server = :my_server
```